# Getting this error when connecting mongodb in docker-compose with spring-boot application

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose

"ctx":"conn18","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"user","authenticationDatabase":"user_db","remote":"172.20.0.8:51928","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user "user" for db "user_db""}}

where **user** is my username & **user_db** is the database name

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `authSource=admin` at the end of the `uri` in spring-boot `application.yml` file

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/user_db?authSource=admin
```

Comment: no it doesnt fix it, still wont connect `MONGO_URI_PROD=mongodb://${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}@mongo:27017/${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}?authSource=admin`

Comment: Probably you have some other issue also along with this one.

Comment: i had to delete files from volume too